# Git commit unknown Author

Tags: git, github

I am commiting through the command line. 
When I commit I have to enter my username, but when I check through the browser the Author appears as **unknown** ..  WTF !

[image]

Comment: Did you enter your username  to commit or to push?

Comment: I recently had this same problem with BitBucket.  I am curious to see what the solution is.

Comment: solution is below @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your default global username is not set, which will most certainly cause this error.
Please try the following command, then make a commit and push..

```
git config --global user.name myname
```

If this works, from here on out you will be able to commit and it will show with your username. Let me know what happens so I can assist you further if you need.